# Regular Expression

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I have two ways to  check a string for a special characters in 11g

1 ) **Using SELECT**

```
V_CNT_QRY := ' SELECT LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(:1,
                                             ''
                                             abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 '',
                                             '' '')))
                  from dual ';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  V_CNT_QRY INTO V_CNT USING V_COLUMN_DATA;
```

2)  **Using a procedure**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Validate_Inputstring(input_String IN VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN
  IF REGEXP_LIKE(input_String, '^[A-Z0-9a-z]*$') THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('U have entered alphanumeric chars--->' ||
                         input_String);
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('U NOT have entered alphanumeric chars---->' ||
                         input_String);
  END IF;
END;
```

Please suggest a better way

Comment: Why not put the expression from the former in a function?

Comment: What I mean is: there's no need to type in the `translate` call every time you need it. You can just create a function for it and hide all the ugly details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table testx
( val1 varchar2(50));

insert into testx (val1) values ('Some ' || chr(9) || 'bad string');
insert into testx (val1) values ('Some nice string with 123 numbers');
commit;

select val1, regexp_instr(val1, '[^[:alnum:] ]') from testx;
```

The select will return 0 if string contains only alphanumeric or spaces, else > 0.

So, you can add a where clause to grab just the "bad" strings:

```
select val1 from testx where regexp_instr(val1, '[^[:alnum:] ]') > 0;
```

Of course you can modify this as needed depending on your definition of "special characters".

EDIT:
if you don't care about flagging punctuation, try:

```
select val1 from testx where regexp_instr(val1, '[^[:alnum:] [:punct:]]') > 0;
```

again, modify as needed to your definition

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you want to check if the string contains only ASCII characters, you can use this:

```
Select 'No'
  From dual
 Where LENGTH(ASCIISTR(:input_String)) != LENGTH(:input_String)
 Union
Select 'Yes'
  From dual
 Where LENGTH(ASCIISTR(:input_String)) = LENGTH(:input_String)
```

HTH

Answer (score 2):

I would use the **regexp_replace** function in the following way:

```
select 'You have'|| decode(regexp_replace (:txt,'^[A-Z0-9a-z]*$', '1'), '1', ' ', ' not ')  || 'entered a string composed only by alphanum characters' from dual;
```

The bind variable *txt* contains the string to validate.